# Jenkins freestyle job: Difference between GitHub project URL and Git repositories

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, jobs, continuous-delivery

I know how to use a SCM like GitHub in Jenkins freestyle project in order to create a simple build. But I am trying to understand the difference between using a GitHub repository in the **SCM section** of the build vs. using the GitHub project URL in the **general section** of the build?

I think it's easier if I add 2 screenshots for you to take a look at:

*This is in the General section of the freestyle project:*

[image]

*This is in the SCM section of the freestyle project:*

[image]

Comment: I believe the first one is used for accessing the GitHub API, e.g. for build status reporting (see https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/), whereas the second is just for accessing the code itself (any git provider).

Comment: Yes, seems like you can do different kinds of linking between your Jenkins server and your GitHub repositories.